# How to reduce following expression so that it less computation.

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, inverse, factorial, fibonacci-numbers

I am using following expression in one of my programs

$$P = \left \lfloor \frac{\sum_{i=N}^M F(i) \cdot i!}{K}\right \rfloor \mod p.$$

Here $N$, $M$, $K$ and $P$ are non-negative integers, $N \leq M$ and $p$ is a prime number. Moreover, $F(i)$ returns the $i$th Fibonacci number, i.e.
$$ F(i+1) = F(i) + F(i-1)$$
with $F(1) = F(0) = 1$.

It is very time consuming to evaluate this expression. What can I possibly do to reduce the runtime?

Comment: Try to expand $fibonacci(i)$ iteratively, this will give you more information!

Comment: How are you computing the Fibonacci numbers?  Would using something like [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) be more efficient?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I can't use Binet's formula as it will impossible to calculate when value of n will be very high. I'm using normal iteration for calculating $fibonacci(i)$

Comment: I added $mod 10000019$ to the whole result. But to do modular computation, I have to calculate summation first which is impossible for me.

Comment: Compute $F_i=fibonacci(i), P_i=i!$ for $i=N-1, N-2$ before starting summation. In the summation loop update only $F_i = F_{i-1} + F_{i-2},  P_i = P_{i-1} \times i$ with the recursion formulas.  This avoids recomputing the complete $F_i, i!$ for each summation step.

Comment: @gammatester But If I'll do summation at once then summation result is going to be very huge and it may give unexpected results.

Comment: Then reduce every summand mod p

Comment: We need to prevent overflow. Write $F_i = P q_i + r_i$ using long division. The remainders satisfy $r_{i+2} \equiv r_{i+1} + r_i \mod P$. What is needed is a solution of this recurrence. Then we can proceed as suggested by gammatester.

Comment: @CarlChristian sir, thank you for your inputs but I'm not able to infer it properly. Can you please explain it as answer?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If you implement Binet in the obvious way using floating-point numbers you're  not going to get the right answer for large $n$ because floating-point is not exact. Now, in Python it's not hard to concoct a class that does exact arithmetic in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]$...

Comment: @gammatester, if I reduce every sum by mod p. will it give me proper result, because I'm also dividing the whole summation with value K?.

Is 
$\frac{\frac{fib(i)*i!}{mod p} + \frac{fib(i+1)*(i+1)!}{mod p}}{k} = \frac{\frac{fib(i)*i! + fib(i+1)*(i+1)!}{k}}{mod p}$

Comment: @CarlChristian now I understood your solution but I think it will change the result because I've to apply mod p only after division of summation by k.

Comment: I see. What happens when $K$ does not divide the sum?

Comment: @CarlChristian I need Quotient so I've to divide the sum by $K$ to get Quotient. I updated my question also

Comment: How do you do $(142/8) = 17 \pmod {19}$?

Comment: @Magdiragdag I took floor value of $142/8$ which is $17$.

Comment: @Sadhu I see that you modified the question to add a floor operator. Then you must compute the full result in the integers, not reducing mod $p$ at every step, and only do the mod $p$ at the end. Where did you get this problem from? Project Euler? I consider it extremely likely that in the specific context of the problem, the sum is always evenly divisible by $K$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: Technically, it not necessary to form the complete sum before doing the division with $K$. If $s = s_1 + s_2$ and $s_i = q_i K + r_i$, and $r_1 + r_2 = q_3 K + r_3$ then $s = (q_1 + q_2 + q_3) K + r_3$. Breaking the sum into partial sums and doing long division with $K$ will help keep the intermediate results small.

Comment: I have done a major edit of your question. Feel free to roll it back. I have rephrased your question based on my understanding of your problem. I deleted your edits only because they had served their purpose, i.e., they explained why the floor operator was needed.

Comment: It would be a very nice edit if you explain why this formula is relevant to you. I don't question that it is relevant to you, but you will earn goodwill by doing this. Any additional information about the relevant input parameters is crucial. In particular, you must address @Magdiragdag last comment.

Comment: Thank you so much  @CarlChristian for such a wonderful edit.

Comment: While the summands cannot properly be reduced by $\bmod p$ as they are formed, they can be reduced $\mod pK$.  Whether this helps depends on the relative sizes of $p,K,M,N$, which the Question does not illuminate in its current form.  Nonetheless your Comments indicate an involvement in the understanding of the problem, so I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly someone has a simplification for that sum. In case not, an off-topic on the programming. It's possible that the problem is you're using a very bad implementation of Fib. That is, if your code looks like this:

`def Fib(n):
  if n < 2:
    return 1
  return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)`

then there's your problem! This is hugely inefficent - calling Fib(n) leads to Fib(n) calls to Fib(), most of which are repetitions of previously calculated values. You can improve this greatly by "memoizing" the function: Store previously calculated values and look them up when needed:

`Fibs = {}
"""Fibs is a "dict" where we record previously calculated values"""
def Fib(n):
  """Try to look up the answer in Fibs; if that doesn't work give up and recurse, storing the answer for next time:"""
  try: 
    return Fibs[n]
  except:
    if n < 2:
      ans = 1
    else:
      ans = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
    Fibs[n] = ans
    return ans`

The second version will be *much* faster than the first.

Similarly you probably want to memoize your Factorial(); there the obvious recursive version is less awful  since there's only one recursive call, but it's still pretty bad.

Serious Python guys should write a "decorator" @Memoize, allowing you to write the first version and have it automatically execute like the second version.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm using memoization in my program, but it's giving me ambiguous results, when value is very high.

Comment: @Sadhu Where "ambiguous" results are _wrong_ results? If the problem is integer overflow one solution is to use Python...

Comment: We've got a least recently used cache decorator in the standard library [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). FWIW, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683466/4014959) some code that tests various Fibonacci algorithms in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another  way to calculate $F_n$ efficiently, in fact in time $\log n$:

First get $2\times 2$ matrix multiplication working. Now define $$X_n=\begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1}\\F_n\end{bmatrix}.$$Note that $$X_{n+1}
=AX_n,$$where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

So you just have to calculate $A^n$, which you can do efficiently using [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). (This probably makes more sense if for some reason you need just one value of $F_n$.)